# Yii 1.1 custom Error handling for my controller

Tags: php, yii, error-handling, yii1.x

i use Yii 1.1 and i have Controller for performing JSON service calls and i want to handle "Page Not Found" error specifically in that Controller.
is there a way to do that?

i have set a general error handling in my "main.param". i just need to handle it differently in one of my controllers. tnx

Comment: use try catch block in your controller

Answer (score 2):

You can use error handling

```
throw new CHttpException(404,'The specified post cannot be found.');
```

You can see this doc for detail 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error

You can handling in your controller like this

```
public function yourActionFunction($yourParam)
{
    $model= YourClass::model()->yourModelFunction($yourParam);

    if($model===null)

        throw new CHttpException(404,'My personal messge  - The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: this method throws the error. i have set a general error handling in my "main.param". i just need to handle it differently in one of my controllers. tnx

Comment: I have update the answer.. i hope is useful